# Flexbox equal height (with diffrent size content) not working

Tags: html, wordpress, css, flexbox

I am trying to use Flexbox to create a grid to output WordPress latest posts on my home page. But because the content within each box is different, the height of each box isn't equal, and that create issues. I tried using align-item=justify and a few other recommended options, but nothing seems to be working.

Here is the CSS I am using:

```
.home-latest-posts {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.home-latest-posts .post {
     background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    width: 32%;
}
.home-latest-posts .post:nth-child(3n+2) {
   margin-left: 2%;
   margin-right: 2%;
}
.home-latest-posts .post .entry-title {
  padding: 1em 3em 0.5em;
}
.home-latest-posts .post .entry-content {
 padding: 0 3em 1em;
}
```

However, since there may be other codes that may be interfering, I'll link to the actual page so you guys can get the whole picture.

You can see the issue I am having at this test site (http://moneyrope.com/). It's the section under "Latest Money Tips".

Sorry about the mess. It's just a test site.

Answer (score 1):

Add this part

```css
.widget-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.home-latest-posts .post {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

Don't forget to [prefix](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) all your code. You should also consider wrapping it inside a `min-width` @media query

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help. I added the code you provided.                                                                                                                                                                                                                         It kind of works, but it somehow makes the height of the very last box taller than the others!? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By the way, thank you for the advice on prefixing and the link. I will make sure to do that. Thanks again.

Comment: It shouldn't make the last item taller and I can't reproduce the issue you're describing. Most probably, something else in your CSS interferes. Without being able to observe it, I can't fix it. Please provide a working example.

Comment: I got it. Apparently, on line `875` of `/wp-content/themes/moneypantry/style.css` you have `.featured-content .entry:last-of-type { margin-bottom: 0; }`. Either delete that rule or make the `margin-bottom` rule in what I posted stronger so it overrides the one you have.

Comment: Please note this discussion and your question are on the borderline of being off-topic on this website. SO is dedicated to helping programmers ***learn how to do their own work***, not to ***providing debugging or coding services for free***. An easy way to determine if your question is good or bad, is to ask yourself if the answer you are searching for is only able to help your specific case or if it could help other people solve similar problems. You are getting dangerously close to the ***fix my website for free*** pattern. For that, you must hire a developer. Kind regards,